# PrimeFaces push and Glassfish

Tags: primefaces, glassfish

I'm using:
Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (build 5)
Primefaces 3.4.1
Firefox 10.0.0.7 on Linux

Does Primefaces Push work on Glassfish? I ask because when I hit my *.xhtml pages, I keep getting ClassNotFoundExceptions. So I would get a not found exception, download the jar and add new class is not found. So far I've got these jars ...

atmosphere-cometd-1.0.2.jar
atmosphere-runtime-1.0.2.jar
cataline-6.0.20.jar

But my next ClassNotFoundException is org.jboss.servlet.http.HttpEventServlet and because I'm using Glassfish, it's making me wonder if I'm doing this right.

All I'm trying to do is send a message from a MDB into a webpage via primepush and have it appear as a notification in growl.

I've added the following to my web.xml.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is in my *.xhtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleMessage(msg) {
        msg.severity = 'info';
        grow.show([msg]);
    }
</script>

    <p:socket channel="/notifications" onMessage="handleMessage"/>
```

And this is in my message driven bean.

```
PushContext pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();

pushContext.push("/notifications", new FacesMessage("Test Summary", "Test Detail"));
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you the one who created the project from scratch ? Did it run on JBoss before you put it to run on glassfish ?

Comment: Ummm, I did create my project from scratch, but I have not run it on JBoss. I doubt if I am "the one".

Comment: Update: I continued adding more jars which I found from my fake maven project and got past these errors. Then I enabled the comet protocol within glassfish. Still not working but my further issues do not relate to this topic anymore. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you don't have jboss runtime in your build path and you have glassfish runtime ?

Comment: Yes, I just continued to add the jars after pulling them out of my fake maven project using atmosphere, and these errors went away.

Answer (score 1):

in glassfish 3.1.2 and primefaces 3.4

I add the following to got the facesmessage example to work.

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.PUSH_SERVER_URL</param-name>
    <param-value>http://localhost:8080</param-value>
</context-param>
```

pom.xml (for maven)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I don't use maven which does seem to make things a bit more difficult in this case. I use ant. I created an example maven project just to download the atmosphere jars and then I would pull them out of that and add them to my project. Anyways, I've got much the same as you there.